# Strange csv output when csv file is read from a github repo using pandas on Debian OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, debian

I have the following data on a csv file:

```
XG,612.0
YG,-1924.0500000000002
ZG,-959.085
A_mod,6.889112523645457
I1_mod,0.478595694542785
I2_mod,32.64258822366686
```

If I open it using excel or atom, everything's normal. The file is on the folder of my GitHub repo, I don't know if this is important, it shouldn't, but when I read it using the `pd.read_csv()` function on python, I got the following result:

[image]

It seems like pandas is reading some kind of metadata from the file, but not the file itself. I'm running python 3.6 from Jupyterlab on a Debian Google Cloud VM instance. I don't think all of this should be a problem but this is the first time I'm seeing this happening and I have no clue about what's happening.

Could someone please tell me how to fix this problem and explain why is it caused?

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT**

The files are contained in the local folder cloned via URL from the github website. So basically using `git clone` to your local machine should produce the same effect.

In python, i'm using `pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')`.

Anotehr curious thing, is that on my personal machine under windows 10 i have no problem at all reading the files. But in the Google Cloud VM instance using exactly the same procedure is where i'm having this strange issue.

Comment: It would probably help to show how _exactly_ you read the file from the github repo - [mcve]

Comment: Allright, i'll add an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the Git LFS pointer file instead of the actual file. `version`, `oid` and `size` are parts of the Git LFS [spec](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md). Git LFS keeps these files in lieu of the actual large data files in the repository. They are supposed to be seamlessly replaced on checkout.

Check the output of the `git clone` on the box where you get the wrong result. There seems to be a configuration problem with Git LFS.

Comment: Hi w-m, thanks a lot for your answer!! indeed yes i used the git lfs library to upload some large files. Is there anyway to untrack this files or locate the original files this pointer is pointing to?? Thank you again

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know enough about Git LFS to troubleshoot this problem with you. I suggest you create another question where you detail what you did to create the large file and list the output of the git clone commands both on your Windows 10 machine and on the cloud server doing a fresh checkout!